# popup notifications for google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, android-notifications, google-gdk, android-toast

How do i make custom popup notifications for google glass the way it is shown in the google glass commercial. I want my service to run on the background and send timely popups only when necessary.

Link for reference 
http://www.mobile88.com.sg/news/read.asp?file=/2012/5/11/20120511113022&phone=Google_Glass_augmented_reality__futuristic_concept

Is there a possible way to do so or should I just use only Toast notifications or invoke activities through intents.

Answer (score 2):

The "popup" design from that conceptual video was tested by the Glass team before it was released to the public and found to be overly distracting. It evolved into the concept of timeline notifications which are not as invasive, but which still act as timely alerts only when appropriate.

These timeline notifications can generally be done in one of two ways, depending on your exact use case:

1. Your app or webapp can use the Mirror API to insert a timeline item at the appropriate time with a notification sound. Users will hear the sound and, if they are in a position to do so, can wake Glass to see the card.
2. Your GDK app can create a LiveCard and publish it with `LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL` which will automatically display the card right after you publish it.